# How to define "external" StorageAccount in Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

So i am writing a small Azure Function to count the total amount of unique entities in a StorageAccount Table. So far everything works, except for the connection to the Storage Table. During the development i used the StorageAccount of the Function and it worked fine. But now i need to connect to a different StorageAccount Table.

This is what i got so far:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Onkeliroh.Test
{
    public static class TableStorageEntityCounter
    {
        [StorageAccount("fwetabletest")]
        [FunctionName("TableStorageEntityCounter")]
        public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
                                     [Table("BlaBlub", Connection = "fwetabletest")]CloudTable cloudTable,
                                     ILogger log)
        {
            var totalCount = await GetCountOfEntitiesInPartition(cloudTable);

            log.LogInformation("Total Entity Count:" + totalCount.ToString());
        }

        public static async Task<int> GetCountOfEntitiesInPartition(CloudTable table)
        { \\[...]
        }
    }
}
```

The "external" StorageAccount i located in the same ResourceGroup.

My Question is: How to i tell my function to use the other StorageAccount? The `StorageAccount` decorator -- apparently -- isn't working.

Comment: You should have an AppSetting "fwetabletest" which contains the connection string to your external storage. That should all work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Connection` parameter in the `TableAttribute` tells your binding which storage connection string setting to take from your settings file (locally) or the App Settings (in Azure).

So this: `[Table("BlaBlub", Connection = "fwetabletest")]` means you're telling the binding the name of the connection string setting is **fwetabletest**. Make sure to have a connection string setting named **fwetabletest** pointing to the 'external' storage account under the Function App Configuration and you should be good to go.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should actually define it in the config level and create the client accordingly, you can have the connection string in the settings.json file and access it as

```
   private static readonly string BLOB_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
```

[`SAMPLE CODE`](https://github.com/jamesfulford/azure-functions-image-processing/blob/master/HW4AzureFunctions/Configuration.cs)

Comment: how do i define it at the config level? as far as i know, C# Azure Functions are parsed during the build and i have no chance on editing the `function.json` by myselfe.

Comment: you can set it on the portal by going to your function and then connection strings